# NullPointer within JUnit test using @Before

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The below code produces a NullPointerException when I run it. Which is weird because shouldn't the `setup()` method be ran before the tests?

If I instantiate the AirJourney class within the test method the JUnit test passes without any problems. What am I missing?

```
private AirJourney journey;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        journey = new AirJourney(4, 800, "A", "B");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCorrectCostIsProduced()
    {
        assertEquals(32000, journey.calculateCostOfJourney());
    }
```

Comment: Did you miss `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`?

Comment: Where does that NPE occur?

Comment: @ernest_k The call to `journey.calculateCostOfJourney()`